# jQuery modal on pageload disappearing because of age verification overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Wasn't sure of the best way to word the title but here's the gist of it: I made an ecommerce site for a client a couple months ago, it's marijuana related merch, so they wanted an age verification. I made that with a javascript overlay. Now they want a disclaimer to launch after age verification and before the homepage.

I made a jquery modal that fires on pageload with a cookie so it doesn't pop up every time you go to the home page. Unfortunately the cookie registers when the age verification loads, so when you submit your age, the cookie is registered and the disclaimer is gone before you get a chance to see it.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function(){
  var check_cookie = $.cookie('ss_manifesto');
   if(check_cookie == null){
     $.cookie('ss_manifesto', '1', { expires: 7 });
  $("#ModalMessage").dialog({modal: true});
}
});
  </script>
```

Is there a way to edit the `check_cookie` to be `null | 1` or something, and then make the value to be +1 on each load? That way it has to get to a value of 2 before the disclaimer is removed?

EDIT:

I added this hoping to set the cookie on clicking to exit modal but it's not setting anything.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var check_cookie = $.cookie('ss_manifesto');
   if(check_cookie == null){
  $("#ModalMessage").dialog({modal: true});
   }
  $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click(function(){
   $.cookie('ss_manifesto', '1', { expires: 7 })
  });  
  });
```

Comment: set cookie after showing the modal. and don't show modal if cookie is set. simple i think. If you want to increment count, then take value from cookie, convert or cast (parseInt) to int and increment. Then save. If cookie isn't set, consider it as 0.

Comment: The page is reloaded when the age verification is submitted though. So the cookie gets set while the modal is still hidden, and then on the reload from age verify, gets omitted on the reload.

Comment: Then you have to submit the page asynchronously using ajax. Or insert an hidden field and set some value to it on age submit. Set cookie only if you found that value. (if hiidenfield value then set cookie, if cookie then no pupup)

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void AgeSubmit_event(object sender,EventArgs e)

    {
    hdnPopupState.Value="1";
    }
```

in jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var check_cookie = $.cookie('ss_manifesto');
   if(check_cookie == null && $("#hdnPopupState").val()=="1"){
     $.cookie('ss_manifesto', '1', { expires: 7 });
    }
   if($.cookie('ss_manifesto')==null)
    {
     $("#ModalMessage").dialog({modal: true});
    }
});
```